# ffmpeg avcodec_send_packet(_codecCtx, &_packet)

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264

[part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cU3n.png)[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0bgX.png)[part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2pg.png)
I am using ffmpeg for decoding H.264 video in iOS platform, when running the following function :

```
avcodec_send_packet(_codecCtx, &_packet)
```

I got this error :

```
"Thread 5" EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code =1, address = 0x6))
```

Comment: provide more code snippet, ffmpeg library will throw lots of errors if you don't setup things currently, there is a good chance that the real problem is not from send packet function its self

Comment: Thanks, I have added the whole code snippet above. Part1,2,3